# Android GCM-App won't run unless you update Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM Push Notification Code in my Android Project. While running on real Devices, every times it ask me to Update Google Play Services.

I am using the following version for GCM library:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

I am using the same code from Android quickStart Sample:
[Sample Code Link](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm)

I am targeting my App for 5.0 and above Devices. Is there any way, so that I can switch to lowest library version of GCM that majority of Android 5.0 comes with.
So that I need to install updated version of Google Play Services while running my App.

Answer (score 1):

Always compile your project with the latest version which support libraries. They run on all version previous versions of Android. 
All Android 2.3, 4.x, 5.x, 6.x version run the same latest version of the latest support libraries.

Current latest version of support libraries are

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

The whole point of providing Play Services and Support libraries is that Google can update following libraries on all phones without updating the core Android OS.

If you get message on your phone that you need to update Play Services then please do so. Without having the latest version of Play Services many apps will have problems to run.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am compiling my code using support library 22.1.1.Beacuse of HTTP connection classes which now have been changed to URL connection. now I need to migrate my code to Maven Environment. How can I add  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
this GCM dependency in my pom.xml file. Thanks for any help.